# My home page not working for spring mvc web app.When I am running the application I am getting 404 error.Please

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please see the code below 
log files
2017-11-06 23:34:15 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring' processing GET request for [/Insurance1/]%2017-11-06 23:34:15 WARN  PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Insurance1/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring'%2017-11-06 23:34:15 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:996 - Successfully completed request%

```
1.Dispatcher servlet:

<pre><code>


     <context:component-scan base-package="Insurance1.Controller" />

        <bean> 
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/View/"></property>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
        </bean>

  </code> </pre>



2.    Web.xml:

<pre><code>

    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rootApplicationcontext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
          <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

     <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    </web-app>  

</code></pre>

    3.My controller
<pre><code>
    @Controller 
    public class Helloworld {

        @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home","/Insurance1/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite");
            return "welcome";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String adminPage(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
            return "admin";
        }
    </code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home","/Insurance1/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I think, you should change that to

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home","/Insurance1" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I did but the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application's context name is `/abc` and the port on which your server is running is `XXXX`, just try to send request to http://localhost:XXXX/abc/Insurance1/. Just replace 'XXXX' with the actual port number on which tomcat is running and replace 'abc' with the actual context of the application. Let me know whether it helps.